# How do I see site blocked from Safari's Top Sites?

Tags: safari, settings

Safari's Top Sites has two buttons, the X to remove and the pin to "pin" the item to the Top Sites.

The pin is easy to see (hover over the site images) and "undo" (you just click it again), but if you click the X you've essentially black-listed the website (or at least the specific URL) so it won't come appear in top sites to review or undo. The problem is, accidentally blocked sites, or sites I've changed my mind about, can't be reviewed easily.

For a specific site that I know is missing, its easy enough to manually add it to top sites (same as adding a regular bookmark), but I can't find any way of viewing the list of sites blocked from Top Sites.

Is there a way to see/edit the list of black-listed items from Top Sites?

Or even just a way to reset the Top Sites deletions (and pins if necessary) entirely, without losing all safari browsing history/etc? (This would make it simple to re-block and re-pin the few still-valid exceptions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of blocked sites is in the **BannedURLStrings** array in ~/Library/Safari/TopSites.plist